# no module named 'keras.legacy'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am working on speech recognition where I have to use keras Optimizer.

```
from keras.optimizers import Optimizer
from keras.legacy import interfaces
from keras import backend as K
```

It gives me error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.legacy'
```

I have install anaconda and keras.

Comment: What version of Keras are you using?

Comment: keras verson '2.4.3'

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the Keras team removed the legacy module as of version 2.4.0. (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases)

Try downgrading your version to 2.3.1:
`conda install keras=2.3.1`

Comment: thanks a lot... so can you tell what can i use instead of keras.legacy for interface?

Comment: You can use keras.legacy if you downgrade to 2.3.1. According to the link I provided, the Keras team discontinued multi-backend support (which I am assuming is what the legacy module provides) and are now building Keras as part of tensorflow. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Keras to know if there is another way to do the same thing you are trying to do, but in the current version.